# is there ros support for yaskawa motoman nxc100?

Tags: ros, motoman

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if not, can I create it myself somehow?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217744/is-there-ros-support-for-yaskawa-motoman-nxc100?/) by [shaigiv](https://answers.ros.org/users/23901/shaigiv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As for ROS-Industrial (with the `motoman_driver` package), there is no support for the NXC 100 controller.

From an answer by Eric Marcel (Yaskawa America) on [Does ROS SUPPORT the NXC100 Controller](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/swri-ros-pkg-dev/-ZmCWI3CcjM/p9KSn6ohrdsJ) on the ROS-Industrial [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev):

> Unfortunately, the NXC controller is an older generation and doesn't support MotoPlus API on which the ROS driver is built. For a controller of similar size to the NXC, you would need to get the FS100 controller with a new robot.

There are some alternative ways to communicate with those controllers, but they will be less performant than MotoPlus and `motoman_driver`:

> Otherwise, for remote controller of the NXC you can use the "Ethernet Server function" or MotoCom API (for Windows).
> In theory, you might be able write a ROS driver to send motion instruction through the "Ethernet Server" but there are limitations.
> Communication response is fairly slow (around 60 ms) and you can only queue one motion at the time, so the robot need to reach its set destination before you can send the next destination.

So to answer your question:

> is there ros support for yaskawa motoman nxc100?

No.

> if not, can I create it myself somehow?

Yes, but there will be performance issues, and you would not be able to reuse the [industrial_robot_client](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_robot_client) and / or [motoman_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver) packages (without modifications), and it will probably require quite some effort, as the MotoCOM API is apparently targeted mainly at Windows.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0